# 大型スクリーンiPhoneのランドスケープモードで意図せずSplitViewになる

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

iOS17,iPhone15ProMaxなどの大型スクリーンiPhoneのランドスケープモードでSplitViewモードになってしまい、アプリが正常に表示されません。(iPhone15などでは問題ありません）

アプリはXcode上でTarget>Info>Application Scene Manifest>Enable Multiple WindowsはNoに設定してMultiple Windows非対応になっているため、iPad上では問題なく動作するのですが、上記のiPhone上だとこちらの設定が反映されず、SplitViewモードに入ってしまいます。

大型スクリーンiPhoneでSplitViewを回避する方法がありましたら、ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

以下の記事を参考に自己解決しました。

`NavigationView` の `NavigationViewStyle` に `.stack` を適用で解決。

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

[【SwiftUI】NavigationViewを使用したアプリをiPadで表示させたら身に覚えのない白いViewが表示された時の対処法](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/who-are-view/)